# Django broken pipe when displaying a lot of static content?

Tags: django

I am working in Django debug mode. I have a Django view that displays **a lot** of images, like 1000.
Previously, I was sending the following Django response for each image:

```
django.http.HttpResponseRedirect("/static/thumbs/%s" % thumbnail_filename(url))
```

i.e. I was redirecting to Django static file serving.
The page would load and then the images would start to trickle in.

I switched to using static file serving (still in debug mode), using the Django static app. Now, the runserver log shows the images loading much more quickly, but it breaks a few seconds in with the following error:

```
self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

On the browser side, I see the Chrome crash message "Aw, Snap!".

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Well, the pipe is broken because the browser crashed. So, don't crash the browser.

Comment: I'd second checking that. Are you sure the problem isn't invalid data, or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I recently bumped into this problem. Django is not supposed to return static files in production. In default Django configuration, static files are supposed to be served by a dedicated webserver(e.g. Nginx, Apache, etc) server in front of Django.

To be able to serve static files with Django Django has the option to use an app called `django.contrib.staticfiles` which should be included in the [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS) setting.

By default `INSTALLED_APPS = []`, so you will need to add it manually, for example:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ django.contrib.staticfiles ]`